# Duplicate rows on uitableview when scrolling with custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSString *cellIdentifier=@"menucell";

MenuCell *cell = (MenuCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell==nil)
    cell= [[MenuCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] ;

MenuModel *resturntent = (self.menuList)[indexPath.row];
cell.foodNameLbl.text = resturntent.MenuName;
cell.priceLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@"$" , resturntent.MenuRate];
cell.foodImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"full_breakfast.jpg"];
return cell;
}
```

While scrolling uitextfields values gets duplicates .

I need help to fix this issues

Comment: Where you're using textfields..?? Elaborate more about your issues?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, your cells will be reused. This means when the user scrolls the `tableview`, a `cell` which moves out of the screen will be reused to display the contents of a `cell` which is about to move onto the screen.

Even though this helps in saving memory, the problem it causes is the that the `cell` needs to be prepared for display before it is loaded with the content of the new `cell`.

In your case, it seems you need to maintain the values the user has entered in a `textfield` of a `cell`.

So to fix your problem, if there are not that many `cells` in the `tableview`, simply stop reusing the `cell`. Else whenever the user enters a value in the `textfield` of a `cell`, save it in an `array` (`array` of 'MenuModel' in your case). And fetch the value from from the model and set it to your `textfield` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like your have set values for other `labels`.